# VS 2015 - Debugger does not move after catch line

Tags: .net, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I am debugging my application, the flow is as:

1. Step into method
2. Encounter `Exception`
3. Go to `catch` block
4. Here starts the trouble

Debugging suddenly ends. Not like the VS stops, it and my program are still running, but I am not able to move beyond this point.

(A) Before the point
[image]

(B)
After the point
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` ON worked for me. Now I can step through code as expected.

It is under **Debug** > **Options** > **General**